# Блокировщик рекламы на Youtube своими руками

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имею небольшое расширение для удобной регуляции скорости видео Youtube. Решил добавить функцию ускоренного воспроизведения рекламы - типа блокировщик.

Можно ли сделать это:

- без счетчиков, чтобы срабатывало сразу, а не через интервал?
- если что-то можно сделать "красивее", тоже буду благодарен за советы :)

```
    setInterval(function() {
        if (document.querySelector("div.ad-showing")) {
            document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 16;
            document.querySelector('video').muted = true;
            document.querySelector('.ytp-ad-player-overlay-skip-or-preview').style.cssText = "background: #181818; z-index: 10; position: absolute;";
        } else {}
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Скорее всего [Observer](https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer) это то что вам надо

Comment: Не совсем понимаю зачем вам `else {}` в конце, он ведь никакой роли не играет, советую вам убрать его. И да, согласен со @SwaD, [`MutationObserver`](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) это то что вам нужно.